# Facebook Connect stops working after uploaded to google play

Tags: android, facebook, google-play

I'm trying to use FB Connect on my app, and everything works fine in the emulator and debugging in a Galaxy Nexus, but after uploading it to google play it stops working.

If I install the app downloading it from Play, my facebook.authorize function returns a DialogError (I just don't know what error because I'm only able to view logcat when the installation is made with eclipse). And it only happens if I have the facebook app installed. So when I uninstall the fb app it works nice...

Maybe is some wrong configuration I've made while preparing facebook SDK on my computer? I pasted all my code below, but don't have any log...

```
public class FacebookConnectActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG_JSON = "json";
static Facebook facebook = new Facebook("11111111111111");
AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
private static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
JSONObject json = null;
Context ctx = this;
boolean callback = false;
private static Context staticContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.resgatar_produto_layout);
    FacebookConnectActivity.staticContext = getApplicationContext();
    Log.e("FacebookConnect", "Activity Started");

    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_LOGIN", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                "Access Token retrieved from SharedPreferences");
    }
    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                "Access Expires retrieved from SharedPreferences");
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "user_photos",
                "user_birthday", "user_hometown", "user_relationships",
                "user_location", "user_work_history", "publish_actions" },
                new DialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        Log.e("FacebookConnect", "User authorized");
                        Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                                "onComplete called at facebook.authorize");
                        Log.e("FacebookConnect", "Access Token: "
                                + facebook.getAccessToken().toString());
                        try {
                            mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
                            mAsyncRunner.request("me",
                                    new SampleRequestListener());
                            Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                                    "AsyncFacebookRunner request started (facebook.authorize.onComplete)");
                            Bundle params = new Bundle();
                            params.putString("link",
                                    "https://apps.facebook.com/qranio_game/");
                            params.putString("picture", "http://www.qranio.com/site/images/logo_qranio_facebook.png");
                            int count = 0;
                            while (json == null && count<20){
                                Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                                        "Waiting for json (facebook.authorize.onComplete)");
                                waiting(1000);
                                count++;
                            }
                            if (!(count<20)){
                                noConnectionAlert();
                            }
                            String usuario = json.getString("first_name");
                            params.putString("name", usuario+" está jogando Qranio para Android");
                            params.putString("caption", "Qranio - Making Learning Fun");
                            params.putString("description", "O Qranio é uma plataforma online que propicia o Saber. Você joga, " +
                                    "aprende, acumula Qi$ e troca por prêmios incríveis! Venha jogar também!");
                            //JSONArray fbArr = new JSONArray("{\"name\":\"Jogar\",\"link\":\"https://apps.facebook.com/qranio_game/\"}");
                            params.putString("actions", "{\"name\":\"Jogar\",\"link\":\"https://apps.facebook.com/qranio_game/\"}");
                            params.putString("display", "touch");
                            facebook.dialog(ctx, "feed", params,
                                    new SampleDialogListener());
                            Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                                    "Post on Wall Dialog called (facebook.authorize.onComplete)");

                            // facebook.
                            // if (facebook.isSessionValid()){

                            // }else{
                            // Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                            // "Invalid facebook session while trying to fetch user data");
                            // }

                        } catch (FacebookError fbe) {
                            Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                                    "facebook.authorize FacebookError "
                                            + fbe.toString());

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                                    "facebook.authorize Exception "
                                            + e.toString());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                        Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                                "FacebookError authorizing: "
                                        + error.toString());
                        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                FacebookConnectActivity.this).create();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Erro");
                        alertDialog
                                .setMessage("Ocorreu um erro com o Facebook, por favor tente novamente.");
                        alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
//Here is where I'm getting the error when downloaded from Play
                        Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                                "Error authorizing: " + e.toString());
                        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                FacebookConnectActivity.this).create();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Erro");
                        alertDialog
                                .setMessage("Erro ao tentar conectar com o facebook, tente novamente.");
                        alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.e("FacebookConnect", "Autorizing canceled");
                        finish();
                    }
                });

    } else {
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new SampleRequestListener());
        Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                "Valid session found, AsyncFacebookRunner request started");

        startDataProcess();
    }

}

public void noConnectionAlert(){
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            FacebookConnectActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Erro");
    alertDialog
            .setMessage("Verifique sua conexão com a internet e tente novamente.");
    alertDialog.setButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(
                        DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
}

public static void waiting (int n){

    long t0, t1;

    t0 =  System.currentTimeMillis();

    do{
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    while (t1 - t0 < n);
}

public static void logoutFB() {
    if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        Log.e("AndroidDashboarDesign",
                "Valid FB session found, logging out");
        AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
        mAsyncRunner.logout(staticContext, new BaseRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.e("AndroidDashboarDesign", "Complete FB logout");
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                Log.e("AndroidDashboarDesign",
                        "(logout) IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
                Log.e("AndroidDashboarDesign",
                        "(logout) FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
                Log.e("AndroidDashboarDesign",
                        "(logout) MalFormedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                Log.e("AndroidDashboarDesign", "(logout) FacebookError: "
                        + e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}

public void startDataProcess() {
    int count = 0;
    while (json == null && count<20){
        Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                "Waiting for json (Valid session found)");
        waiting(1000);
        count++;
    }
    if (!(count<20)){
        noConnectionAlert();

    }else{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
    editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
    editor.commit();

    Log.e("FacebookConnect", "startDataProcess() executed");
    Intent a = new Intent(FacebookConnectActivity.this,
            FacebookDataProcess.class);
    a.putExtra(TAG_JSON, json.toString());
    startActivity(a);
    finish();
    }
}

public class SampleDialogListener extends BaseDialogListener {

    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        Log.e("FacebookConnect", "SampleDialogListener complete");
        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
        if (postId != null) {
            Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                    "(SampleDialogListener) Dialog Success! post_id="
                            + postId);
            //mAsyncRunner.request(postId, new WallPostRequestListener());
            //Log.e("FacebookConnect", "WallPostRequestListener started");
            Toast.makeText(FacebookConnectActivity.this, "Mensagem postada com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startDataProcess();
        } else {
            Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                    "(SampleDialogListener) No wall post made, maybe canceled by user."); // Usuario
                                                                                            // clicou
                                                                                            // em
                                                                                            // Cancelar
            startDataProcess();
        }
    }

    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                "Error authorizing: " + e.toString());
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                FacebookConnectActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Erro");
        alertDialog
                .setMessage("Erro ao tentar conectar com o facebook, não foi possível publicar em seu mural.");
        alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(
                            DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        startDataProcess();
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void onCancel() { // Usuario clicou no X do dialog
        Log.e("FacebookConnect", "Post to Wall Canceled with \"X\" button");
        startDataProcess();
    }
}

public class WallPostRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        Log.e("FacebookConnect", "WallPostRequestListener complete");
        Log.e("FacebookConnect", "(WallPostRequestListener) Got response: "
                + response);
        String message = "<empty>";
        try {
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            message = json.getString("message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                    "(WallPostRequestListener) JSON Error in response: "
                            + e.toString());
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                    "(WallPostRequestListener) Facebook Error: "
                            + e.getMessage());
            // Toast.makeText(ctx, "Erro ao postar no Facebook.",
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        startDataProcess();
    }
}

public class SampleRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        try {

            // process the response here: executed in background thread
            Log.e("FacebookConnect", "SampleRequestListener complete");
            Log.e("SampleRequestListener",
                    "Response: " + response.toString());
            json = Util.parseJson(response);
            Log.e("FacebookConnect", "JSON: " + json.toString());

            // postOnWall();
            // startDataProcess();

            // then post the processed result back to the UI thread
            // if we do not do this, an runtime exception will be generated
            // e.g. "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original
            // thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                    "JSON Error in response (SampleRequestListener): "
                            + e.getMessage());
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            Log.e("FacebookConnect",
                    "Facebook Error at SampleRequestListener: "
                            + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}

public void postOnWall() {
    Looper.prepare();
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("link", "www.qranio.com");
    facebook.dialog(ctx, "feed", params, new SampleDialogListener());
    Log.e("FacebookConnect", "SampleDialogListener started");
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callback = true;
    Log.e("FacebookConnect",
            "Authentication authorizeCallback called (onActivityResult)");

}

}
```

Comment: Did you generate a second app key for your app?

Comment: I'm not sure, did you mean the app's signature that I've pasted on my Facebook app settings?

Comment: If you go to your Facebook Developers Page, under apps. You will see a section for Android Key Hash. When you first created your app you needed to generate one in order for Facebook to work with your app. Now that you have released your app you need a new key that is not a debug key. See below on how to generate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used a different keystore file when you signed your application for distribution.

To fix this, run the same command but change the alias and the location of the keystore to the keystore file that you used for distribution

`keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_ALIAS_HERE -keystore ~/path/to/yourapp.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

and paste the resulting string into your Facebook app's dashboard settings under the Android Key Hash section.

Comment: Well I'm using the same keystore since the I've first uploaded it to Google Play. Furthermore, MOTODEV just doesn't let me export my app with a different keystore (I can't remember the keystore's password, so I've tried to use a new one)... But I'll try your command and post the results here

Comment: I've made that, but now even when debugging from motodev I'm gettig a DialogError saying that it's imposible to stabilish a safe connection. I problably got a wrong key hash with keytool huh? (used debug.keystore and pass:android, just as said in the tutorial)

Comment: I'm not sure if that is related to the key hash issue.  If you are still in development mode and building off of eclipse, you're using the default debug keystore that Android provides.  If you are signing the app to distribute the app to the market and such, then you are using your own private keystore for that.  Make sure that whichever keystore you're using is on the dashboard.  Once you are absolutely sure that you've done it correctly, then any other problems that you are encountering should be irrelevant to the key hash.  Make sure when running the command that it prompts for a pw also.

Comment: I've uploaded a new version wich shows the hash mismatch error in the screen, and I got an different hash key than the one I was using. I was just a matter of pasting it into my fb app configurations. Thank you very much, I was stucked with this for weeks!